# Number of discontinuity points in [0,1]

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, weak-convergence

In the book *Convergence of Probability Measures* by Billingsley. Chapter 3, there is a lemma (lemma 1) as follow,

> *For each $x$ in $D[0,1]$ and each positive $\epsilon$, there exist points $t_0,...,t_v$ such that*$$ 0=t_0<...<t_v=1$$ *and* $$w_x[t_{i-1}, t_i) < \epsilon, \ i=1,...,v.$$

My question is after the proof author says that, from this lemma it follows that there can be at most finitly many points $t$ at which the jump $|x(t)-x(t+)|$ exceeds a given positive number; therefore, $x$ has at most countably many discontinuities.

How do I say this from the lemma I stated?

Comment: I think you mean $|x(t)-x(t-)|$ in your last paragraph...

Comment: @Momo yes yes!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $w_x[t_{i-1},t_i)<\epsilon$ then $|x(s)-x(t)|<\epsilon$ for $s,t\in [t_{i-1},t_i)$

In particular, if $t\in(t_{i-1},t_i)$, one can get a sequence $s_n\in(t_{i-1},t_i)$ and it follows that $s_n\uparrow t$ and $|x(t)-x(s_n)|<\epsilon$. By taking $n\to\infty$, one gets $|x(t)-x(t-)|\le\epsilon$

So $|x(t)-x(t-)|$ can exceed $\epsilon$ only when $t\in\{t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_v\}$, which is a finite number of points.

Now we can write the discontinuities of $x$ as the following union:

$$\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\left\{t : |x(t)-x(t-)|>\frac{1}{n}\right\}$$

... which is a countable union of finite sets, which is itself at most countable.

Comment: What is $r\in (t_{i-1},t_i)$? Is it $t$?

Comment: @Cantor_Set Thanks, corrected.